# how to pass the base64 encoded password to teradatatsql.connect() in python

Tags: python-3.x, teradata

I have used human readable password while connecting to to taradata using tearadatasql package , i am able to connect successfully . but when I try to use the base64 encoded bytes of the same password(base64encoded )  instead of readable , I get an error "The UserId, Password or Account is invalid", the cred

**base64encoded** = base64.b64encode(bytes('readablepassword','utf-8'))
teradatasql.connect('{"host":"server","user":"username","password":"'+base64encoded+'","logmech":"LDAP"}')

can anyone knows , how to pass the base64 encoded password here?

Comment: Nothing in the *teradatasql* [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/) says base64 encoding is supported. There is an encryption mechanism available if the goal is to avoid having a plaintext password in the script.

Comment: Thanks @Fred,you are right, I have also looked at the documentation , but didnt found .is there any other python package  , which supports the base64 encoded password, while connecting to teradat

Comment: None that I am aware of. If the base64 value is being passed to the script, you can use the password= keyword to pass the b64decode value to teradatasql rather than having it be an attribute value in the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

@Fred is correct. The Teradata SQL Driver for Python does not directly support a password specified in base64 encoding.

As @Fred noted, the Teradata SQL Driver for Python does offer a "[Stored Password Protection](https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver#StoredPasswordProtection)" feature.